# Fetch data from last day, week, month and year in Mysql

Tags: mysql, date

I read many topics to fetch data that posted in different periods, but as the Time in my mysql table is in STRING format I couldn't make it happen.

```
SELECT s.user_id, count(*) AS wins, u.username, u.avatar,u.avatar_uploaded
            FROM on_scores AS s
            LEFT JOIN on_users AS u ON (u.userid = s.user_id)
            WHERE s.is_high = '1' AND  DATE(s.date_score)  >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
                        GROUP BY s.user_id
            ORDER BY wins DESC
            LIMIT 10
```

I tried the `STR_TO_DATE` method but still no output.

Comment: How is it formatted? Example data?

Comment: by time() function in mysql insert command like 1361639735

Answer (score 0):

Use the `from_unixtime` function to get the time into a date-like format.

More info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime).

Information on formatting the resultant date - [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Example:

```
select date_sub( from_unixtime( s.datescore ), INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) as monthfromdatevalue;
select datediff( from_unixtime( s.datescore, curdate()) as howlongago_fromtoday;
```

Comment: how to condition it by last weak, month , year ?

Comment: use the `date_sub` function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub   (looks like you know this already...)

Comment: I am not familiar with the usage . would you update your answer by an example ?

Comment: is this correct ? AND FROM_UNIXTIME(  `date_score` ) < DATE_SUB( FROM_UNIXTIME(  `date_score` ) , INTERVAL 7 
DAY )

Comment: It would compare date_score to (itself - 1 week) - that would always be false.